# How do I filter Azure ResourceGroup to find resources without a particular tagname/tagvalue

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I am using the Azure Node JS API to get a list of resourcegroups in a subscription using the ResourceManagementClient.resourceGroups.list option.

Basically, I want to find all resource groups in a subscription where the "keep" tag (whether it exists or not) does not have a value of 'true'.

I can do the inverse with a filter of "tagname eq 'keep' and tagvalue eq 'true'", but all the sensible alternatives I can think of do not work an InvalidFilterInQueryString response back from the REST API.

I have tried:

- "tagname eq 'keep' and tagvalue ne 'true'"
- "not (tagname eq 'keep' and tagvalue eq 'true')"

I have excluded:

- "tagname eq 'keep' and tagvalue eq 'false'" - this looks like it would work, but there it is not equivalent to the behaviour I want.

I realise I could get the set of all resource groups and then subtract from that the set of resourcegroups which match the "tagname eq 'keep' and tagvalue eq 'true'" filter, but surely it should be possible to write this as a single request?

Comment: any answers on this one ? how can i filter by name